# Possible to comment-out JSTL code?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, comments

If you want to temporarily comment-out a piece of JSTL code that you may re-enable later, is this possible?

Would this work?

```
<!--<c:out value="${someVar}"/>-->
```

Answer (score 47):

When you write such comment in your JSP file:

```
<!-- <c:out value="${someVar}"/> -->
```

This means that this comment will be outputed, i.e. present in the generated HTML page.
If you want to hide your code, use the JSP comments:

```
<%-- <c:out value="${someVar}"/> --%>
```

Answer (score 19):

```
<%-- <c:out value="${someVar}"/> --%>
```

This way, none of jstl code inside will be executed.

Comment: A gotcha which I stumbled across was that I tried to put an xml comment as part of the content of a `<c:otherwise>` block. This resulted in a NumberFormatException. Using jsp comments in this case solves the issue.