# How can I add JSP comments (instead of HTML comments) in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, keyboard-shortcuts

When editing JSP pages in Eclipse, I can comment out the current line or selected block with HTML comments (`<!-- -->`) using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>.

However, in JSP files, I usually want to use a JSP comment (`<%-- --%>`) instead. Is there a way to add these comments with a keyboard shortcut instead/as well?

Comment: thats not jstl, its a scriptlet. I would avoid it enitrely.

Comment: Is it? I thought it was a JSP comment? (See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914099/possible-to-comment-out-jstl-code)

Comment: It's at least not "JSTL comment".

Comment: @PaulD.Waite ah, I see ok, that could be quite useful.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I got my JSTLs and JSPs mixed up. Cheers guys.

Comment: You should ask in the [WebTools (WTP) forum group](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=88) on the Eclipse Community Forums. Hope this helps.

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=88

Comment: Gotcha, have done. Just waiting for my topic to be approved.

Comment: Woo, there it is: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/441626/

Answer (score 3):

You would need to create your own code template, `windows > preferences` and then select JSP's, and tutorial [here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-an-eclipse-template-and-how-do-i-use-it.html)

But i would drop eclipse and use intellij, in which case the answer would be `ctrl+/`

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, Eclipse (a Java editor) doesn’t have a built-in keyboard shortcut for commenting out a line with JSP (Java Server Pages) comments? I can see why you’re recommending Intellij.

Comment: Correct.  I recently switched and should have done it years ago - it costs a bit for the ultimate version (but worth every penny imho).